# problems with ranged values and geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to get a stacked bar plot, but (I think) the problem is, that I have ranged y-values:

```
Punkt Tiefe Zersetzungsgrad

JE1 000-050 H10
JE1 050-100 H10
JE1 100-150 H6
JE1 150-200 H6
JE1 200-250 H5
JE1 250-300 Sandmudde
JE1 300-350 Sandmudde
JE1 350-400 Organomudde
JE3 0-50    H10
JE3 50-100  H9
JE3 100-150 H9
JE3 150-200 H8
JE3 200-250 H6
JE3 250-300 H6
JE3 300-350 H6
JE3 350-400 H6
JE3 400-450 Sandmudde
```

Right now, R is just stacking up bars without contexting it to the values in "Tiefe". The bars aren't even the height, they should be. It seems, R is just randomly doing things. I think the problem lies wihtin the y values, as they are ranges and not singular values. I tried a lot of different things, searched through forums etc., but didn't get the idea, what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.
My Code:

```
zer <- read.table("HorizonteAmanda.csv", header = T, sep = ";", dec = ",", comment.char = "#", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")[c(1:17),] 

plot <- ggplot(zer, aes(x = Punkt,y = Tiefe, color = Zersetzungsgrad)) 
plot + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[The image shows the plot, Rstudio is giving me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UhN5.png)

Comment: It belongs to the data, it's the header. It translates to Point(like site, where the data was collected from), depth and decomposition degree.

Comment: Are you sure you want stacked barchart? Could you explain the idea of the visualization?

Comment: I assume, "Tiefe" is treated as a characters / strings. You might try separating the strings and converting to numbers.

Comment: @utubun Yes. The original data is larger than what I've written here. There are over 130 data entries and the ranges are also not all the same. There are values like '28-59' and so on. In the end it should show a depth-profil of the soil we've measured. In the soil samples there are different stages of decomposion, that I want to show. They end at different depths but the maximum is 500cm.

Answer (score 1):

Try to play around this pipeline:

- Modify your data separating your "ranges" into two numeric vars: `ymin` and `ymax` (see the `separate(...)` call below);
- Convert `Punkt` var into `factor` and into `numeric` afterwards (See `mutate(...)` call bellow):

  - Calculate `xmin` and `xmax` for modified `Punkt` (pm .45);
- Use `geom_rect(...)` instead `geom_bar(...)` to build your plot:

  - Set `xmin` and `xmax` of rectangles;
  - Set `ymin` and `ymax` (your depth ranges);
  - Fill rectangles according to the decomposition degree (you might consider other palette thought);
- Relabel your *x-axis* to get rid of numbers and use unique values from `Punkt` var;
- Expand limits for *y-axis* to cover interval from 0 to 500;
- Reverse *y-axis* so naturally planet surface is above and deeper layers are below;
- Apply `theme_few()` from `ggthemes` library, if you want to get rid of ugly default grey background etc.

So one possible solution is:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)

dt %>%
  separate(col = Tiefe, into = c('ymin', 'ymax'), sep = '-', convert = T) %>%
  mutate(Punkt = as.numeric(as.factor(Punkt)))  %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(xmin = Punkt - .45, 
        xmax = Punkt + .45, 
        ymin = ymin, 
        ymax = ymax, 
        fill = Zersetzungsgrad
        )
    ) +
  geom_rect() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:2, labels = unique(dt$Punkt)) +
  expand_limits(y = c(0, 500)) +
  scale_y_reverse(name = 'Tiefe') +
  ggthemes::theme_few()
```

[image: deepness, darkness]

That's probably good idea to modify `Zersetzungsgrad` var, e.g. adding leading zero to all `H*` to change the order to `H05`, `H06`, ..., `H10`.

Data:

```
dt <- read.table(
  text = "
  Punkt Tiefe   Zersetzungsgrad
    JE1 000-050 H10
    JE1 050-100 H10
    JE1 100-150 H6
    JE1 150-200 H6
    JE1 200-250 H5
    JE1 250-300 Sandmudde
    JE1 300-350 Sandmudde
    JE1 350-400 Organomudde
    JE3 0-50    H10
    JE3 50-100  H9
    JE3 100-150 H9
    JE3 150-200 H8
    JE3 200-250 H6
    JE3 250-300 H6
    JE3 300-350 H6
    JE3 350-400 H6
    JE3 400-450 Sandmudde",
  header = T,
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

Comment: OMG! - That works perfectly! I sat yesterday for literally hours in front of R, trying to figure out, what to do. Thank you very much. I have just used it on the complete data set (changed "breaks = 1:8 - because there are 8 levels of Punkt) and it works! 
But could you please explain, why I have to change Punkt into numeric and then back to factor? Or point me to a source, where I can read about it myself.
Again - thank you very much. You helped me a lot!

Comment: @Klonk I am pleased to know, that I could help you with that. `as.numeric(as.factor(Punkt))` is just a convenient way to recode your `Punkt` variable into `numeric` type  (please note that you convert it into `factor` first, and than into `numeric`) which get you positive integers like 1, 2, 3... `geom_rect`,  requires `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax`. So when `Punkt` value is 1,  `xmin = 1 - 0.45 = .55` and `xmax = 1.45` (column width is .9em). For `Punkt == 2` it's `(1.55, 2.45)` (.9 em wide, gap between `Punkt1` and `Punkt2` is 0.5em) and so on. Hope it will help you to.

Comment: Yes, and very important point - if your `Punkt` is already a factor (you can test it by `sapply(dt, class)`) **you don't need to convert it into the factor again** just `as.numeric(Punkt)` will be ok. Moreover, if former is true, you don't need to call `labels = unique(Punkt)` within `scale_x_continuous()` layer. Just do `labels = labels(Punkt)`, that would be enough. Read more abut the `factor` data type, so you'll get more comfortable working with such data.